# Choropleth boundary colour change in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2.18, choropleth

How do you change the colour of the boundaries between areas on a choropleth map in QGIS 2.18 Mac version?

Comment: Could you provide us with a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "symbology" tab, you can select all of the classes and select "change symbol". There you can change the color and size of the outline for all of the classes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also may I ask how you make the map element bigger so to take most of the space within the frame when working in print composer?

Comment: If you select the map frame (try clicking on the outline rather than inside the map), you can drag the corners to increase the size of the map element